How can requires_grad be True immediately after I set it to False within a training loop, but not outside?
I am attempting to train multiple agents in a Multi Agent Reinforcement Learning environment using torchrl's ClipPPOLoss. For some reason, this loss module doesn't want to receive sample log probabilities with requires_grad=True. After collecting several Tensordict frames from the environment using a SyncDataCollector and storing them in a ReplayBuffer, I try to run the following loop:
for ep in range(num_epochs):
    for _ in range(frames_per_batch // minibatch_size):
        subdata = replay_buffer.sample()

        subdata.get(("agents","sample_log_prob")).requires_grad = False

        # this line prints False!
        print(subdata.get(("agents","sample_log_prob")).requires_grad) 

        loss_vals = loss_module(subdata)

Despite the fact that printing subdata.get(("agents","sample_log_prob")).requires_grad prints False, the code above causes an error from the torchrl ClipPPOLoss loss module:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torchrl/objectives/ppo.py in _log_weight(self, tensordict)
    477         prev_log_prob = tensordict.get(self.tensor_keys.sample_log_prob)
    478         if prev_log_prob.requires_grad:
--> 479             raise RuntimeError("tensordict prev_log_prob requires grad.")
    480 
    481         log_weight = (log_prob - prev_log_prob).unsqueeze(-1)

RuntimeError: tensordict prev_log_prob requires grad.

I have checked loss_module.tensor_keys.sample_log_prob to ensure that it points to ("agents", "sample_log_prob"). If I save subdata during the training loop and access ("agents", "sample_log_prob") outside the training loop, I still find requires_grad = False. What factors could be contributing to the tensor requiring a gradient when viewed by the loss module, but not outside the training loop? I'm struggling to debug further because I don't even know where to look.
